# How to do git-flow in TFS

Tags: git-flow

I have just started a new job and their code management is an undisciplined mess. Normally that's ok and I can cope with it but in this place it's ridiculously bad.

They use TFS...there is nothing I can do about this. There is no chance of introducing git but I have been reading about git-flow and I wondered if there is a set of tools the can manage branching and hotfixing like git-flow with the out of the box TFS tools.

At the very least I would appreciate being directed to any documentation, practices, cheat-sheets etc that make the task of teaching a team of programmers to use source control properly easier. This is more than just a software problem its a hearts and mind thing too.

Comment: See this answer on Programmers StackExchange:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/221109/3126 .  It makes the link between git-flow and an earlier article on branching strategies in Perforce.  Perforce is a centralised VCS like TFS so the ideas should map to TFS.  I agree though, a step-by-step cheatsheet like the original git-flow article would be nice.

Comment: A distinction should be made about the Source Control engine being used.  You could use Git with TFS 2013+ and then use follow GitFlow.  If the org won't allow Git repos within TFS and going exclusively with TFS VC then you could follow a GitFlow workflow but doing it by hand.  Like any of them though you just have to adopt a strategy and stick with it.  With VC it's critical to get the folder hierarchy and relationships between branches correct to allow  GitFlow like workflow in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start with the [ALM rangers branching guidance](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Guidance) this will give you a starting point for defining a sane branching strategy. As for tooling, the out of the box tools aren't that bad in TFS 2012, what are the specific problems?